# Determining how port forwarding is configured

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

- Ubuntu Trusty box in AWS
- I have tomcat bound on port 8080
- I installed apache and it automatically bound to port 80
- `curl http://<externalIP>:80` I see the  tomcat start page(original behavior)
- If I `curl http://localhost:80` I see the apache start page
- `curl http://<internalIP>:80` apache start page
- `iptables -L` is clean (defaults)
- `ufw` is off

How do I figure out what’s doing the forwarding?

Comment: If the "original behavior" was for Tomcat to respond on port 80, then how did you configure it? `iptables` or in `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`?

Comment: @techraf - I didn't configure it - not sure who did.  iptables is clean and tomcat is listening on port 8080.

Comment: Stop Apache, test `curl http://<externalIP>:80`. What's the result?

Comment: @techraf - `curl http://<externalIP>:80` tomcat start page.  `curl http://localhost:80` times out.

Comment: Check Tomcat configuration `/etc/tomcat?/server.xml` for `port=80`

Comment: @techraf port=8080.  `netstat -na` says that nothing is bound to port 80.

Comment: If nothing is bound, then disconnect the machine from network and test again.